# Jenkins docker run prints out the "docker run command with secrets" in console output. Is there a way to prevent this?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am starting a docker container using

```
args += " ${agt.docker.environment.collect { k, v -> "-e '$k'='${parse(dsl, v.toString())}'" }.join(' ')}"
                dsl.docker.withRegistry("https://${agt.docker.repository ?: ''}", '') {
                    dsl.docker.image(agt.docker.image).inside(args) { container ->
                        stgClosure()
                    }
                }
```

But this prints out the actual docker run command in the console output,

```
docker run -t -d -u 500:500 -u root --ulimit nofile=6400:6400 --memory 36g --cpus 12 -e CustomerSecret=XXXXXXX
```

I could not find a way to Option to disable echo of executed commands. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It feels like your actual objective here is to mask/redact the `CustomerSecret=XXXXXXX`. In that situation, you can utilize the `withCredentials` plugin for the pipeline.

Comment: @MattSchuchard my main concern is to not print the underlying docker command. I am reading secrets from "withCredentials" and then appending them in args.